# Not able to import ZopeTransactionExtension from command line

Tags: sqlalchemy, pyramid, zope

I have a pyramid application and it has this line

```
from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension
```

It works without any issues

But if I try the same with command line I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy
```

and

```
from zope.sqlalchemy.datamanager import ZopeTransactionExtension
ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy.datamanager
```

I am not really sure why this is so. The docs have the [same line](http://www.zodb.org/zodbbook/transactions.html#a-simple-demonstration) and it seems to work for them at least

Comment: If you use virtualenvs make sure you use the same virtualenv at command line as the one used to run your application.

Comment: Well it is. I am pretty comfortable with python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with mixing pip and easy_install (which `setup.py develop` uses). They do not cooperate well together when it comes to namespaced packages like `zope.*`. I suggest recreating your virtualenv.

Comment: Yeah. I unisnstalled zope.sqlalchemy and installed it again with pip. This works now. Thanks

Comment: Simply uninstalling zope.sqlalchemy and reinstalling it with pip also worked for me to resolve this.

Answer (score 10):

I recently got the same error in both a pyramid application and the terminal. Reinstalling didn't work in this case. Apparently the zope.sqlalchemy project renamed ZopeTransactionExtension to ZopeTransactionEvents in version 1.2 which was released 2019-10-17.

> To make things clearer we renamed the ZopeTransactionExtension class
> to ZopeTransactionEvents. Existing code using the ‘register’ version
> stays compatible.

https://pypi.org/project/zope.sqlalchemy/ under Changes 1.2

To fix this, use `register` when instantiating the DBSession

```
from zope.sqlalchemy import register

DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autoflush=False))
register(DBSession)
```

According to https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.sqlalchemy/issues/37

Comment: For the record: renaming `ZopeTransactionExtension` to `ZopeTransactionEvents` worked for the Python 2.7 to  3.8 update I'm working on. It was more readable within the existing codebase than `import register`, but I might go back and try `register` later.

Comment: I was wrong. See the fix here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64486574/123033

Comment: You *must* use register; you can not just rename the class.  There were some fundamental changes to SqlAlchemy and Zope.Sqlalchemy that require the change.

Comment: Thanks, removed the advice to rename