# What is this ZopeTransactionEvents error with SQLAlchemy while updating a Pyramid application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyramid, pylons

I'm updating Pyramid/SQLAlchemy legacy code to Python 3.8 from an app working fine under Python 2.7, and running it locally. All the necessary requirements are pip installed and setup.py runs without error.

On running `initialise` with my local .ini file, All goes well, the database tables (MariaDB) are all written.

in models.py

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    scoped_session,
    sessionmaker,
    relationship,
    backref,
    synonym,
    )
from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionEvents
#[...]
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionEvents()))
```

in the main app it fails with `'ZopeTransactionEvents' object has no attribute 'after_commit'` at this function, after getting the final input and attempting to add it to the DB at `DBSession.add(user)`:

```py
def do_create_admin_user(self):
    from ..models import User
    from getpass import getpass
    print("Create an administrative user")
    fullname = input("full name: ")
    username = input("username: ")
    if not username:
        self.log.info("missing username - aborted")
        return
    if len(username) > 50:
        self.log.info("username too long - aborted")
        return
    password = getpass("password for {}: ".format(username))

    with transaction.manager:
        user = User(
            username=username,
            fullname=fullname,
            administrator=True,
            password=password
        )
        DBSession.add(user)
    self.log.info("{} created".format(username))
```

Here are the two key parts of the stack trace:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
"[...]sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1055, in __call__
    return self.registry.value
AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'value'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

[cruft omitted]

```sh
"[...]sqlalchemy/orm/deprecated_interfaces.py", line 367, in _adapt_listener
    ls_meth = getattr(listener, meth)
AttributeError: 'ZopeTransactionEvents' object has no attribute 'after_commit'
```

This specific issue halted the process, and despite days of research (and some unproductive hacking) I'm no closer to a solution. This is a legacy project and I'm not previously familiar with Pyramid or SQAlchemy, so finding my way as I go along.

---

### Fixed

In the end, this is what worked i.e. no arguments to `sessionmaker()`

```py
from zope.sqlalchemy import register
# ...
DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
register(DBSession)
```

Now on to the next error.

Comment: What is `transaction.manager`? Is it imported somewhere?

Comment: It's part of the Pyramid/SQLalchemy way: https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/quick_tutorial/databases.html

Comment: Before looking at SQLAlchemy or Pyramid, I would check your own code. There has probably been a change in implementation or interface in the transaction manager since your code was written. Please paste how you define `DBSession`. Current convention is demonstrated in [this step of a Pyramid tutorial](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/tutorials/wiki2/basiclayout.html#content-models-with-the-models-package) after you scroll down a bit.

Comment: added to the question above

Comment: Care to mark my answer as correct then?

Comment: ah go on, then! also see the discussion on the SQLAlchemy forum: https://groups.google.com/g/sqlalchemy/c/GWJ4xEJXexg/m/TPx2XW3IAgAJ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to a breaking change introduced in zope.sqlalchemy v1.2. See details in the [zope.sqlalchemy pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/zope.sqlalchemy/)

> To make things clearer we renamed the ZopeTransactionExtension class to ZopeTransactionEvents. Existing code using the ‘register’ version stays compatible.

### To upgrade from 1.1

Your old code like this:

```py
from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension

DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension(), **options))
```

becomes:

```py
from zope.sqlalchemy import register

DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(**options))
register(DBSession)
```

#### edit

Essentially its a minor breaking change to the `zope.sqlalchemy` API that was introduced in version 1.2, this is now *the way*. Rather than registering the extension via keyword argument, you now register the session explicitly with the `register` callable.

The above is a direct quote from the documentation. It may not be obvious but the use of `**options` refers to optional keyword arguments. If you are not using any keyword arguments then this would be omitted (i.e. just call `sessionmaker()` with no arguments).

Comment: I already changed instances of `ZopeTransactionExtension` to `ZopeTransactionEvents`, and DBSession to `DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionEvents()))`. Seems there are two choices: use 'register' and revert to `ZopeTransactionExtension` or update to `ZopeTransactionEvents`  and change DBSession - more future-proof?

Comment: Thanks, I'll read it again more thoroughly tomorrow - and get my head around the `ZopeTransactionEvents … after_commit` error, and also try reverting to `ZopeTransactionExtension` with `register`…

Comment: Hm. Tried the above update, it produces: `DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(**options))
NameError: name 'options' is not defined` - sticking with trying to fix ` which at least gets me to the original error

Comment: This is the right answer. There may be other factors going on. As you can see from the source code (https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.sqlalchemy/blob/master/src/zope/sqlalchemy/datamanager.py#L293-L329), the call to `register` is required because it invokes the ZopeTransactionExtenstion AND sets up the transaction events.